# ESRI Geometry Union slower than Built in dissolve which is slower than Shapely

Tags: arcpy, shapely, dissolve

I work with point datasets a lot.  We try to keep a running layer of points and update the dataset with new points while removing the old points.  So, we do a lot of checking the extents of the new points with the extents of old points to make sure we're not overwriting new data or keeping old data.

To do that, one of the methods I run is a buffer of the various points and then dissolve all of the buffers into a single polygon.  I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas how to speed up ESRI without third-party software (IT is hesitant to install any third-party "software" and they don't want to install the shapely, GDAL, and fiona libraries on our virtual server).

I did a recent test with one file that had a little over 11k points in it.  I ran ESRI's built-in Buffer tool under the Analysis toolbox and it took just about 4 minutes to buffer at 120m and dissolve all of the features.  My shapely/fiona implementation took 13 seconds.

So, I modified my code to try to use the ESRI geometry features.  Here's the essentials of my code (I also implemented allowing to group features but that is extraneous to this discussion):

```py
tempFC = "ProjectedInput" #the code either copies a projected input or projects the input

fields = ["SHAPE@"]
inputCursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tempFC, fields)
outputCursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outputFC, fields)

geoms = []
for inputFeature in inputCursor:
    geoms.append(inputFeature[0].buffer(bufferDist))

mergedGeom = geoms[0]
for i in range(1, len(geoms)):
    mergedGeom = mergedGeom.union(geoms[i])

outputCursor.insertRow(mergedGeom)
```

The union function is incredibly slow.  <s>I started the above buffer 22 minutes ago and it's only half-way through unioning all of the features.</s>  (It turns out I selected SR_01 instead of SN_01 when I ran the above code.)  With the correct dataset, it took a little under 3 minutes.  So, it was faster than the built-in but still not fast enough.

So, it seems there's not going to be any way to get the shapely speeds out of the arcpy library.  Anyone have any ideas or anything that has worked in the past?

Comment: Forget geometries in this case. Perhaps try intermediate outputs to in_memory space.

Comment: Why are you doing this in python with geometry objects? Why can't you use Buffer_analysis https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000019000000 and Dissolve_management https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000005n000000 ? which is what I think @FelixIP is alluding to. Buffer tempFC to in_memory\temp then dissolve in_memory\temp to outputFC, as both of these are compiled executables they are extremely likely to run faster than *any* python script iterating geometries. Pythons' strong point is high level code not low level crunching.

Comment: @Michael Stimson this is what he was doing using dissolve option in Buffer tool, but it wasn't fast enough and I suggested buffer to memory space suspecting that dissolved buffers is intermediate step. Tools or geometry crunching are terribly slow. I still keep arcview 3 to do something real quick, i.e. seconds instead of 10s minutes.

Comment: I agree @FelixIP. I've found that as computers get faster, following Moores' law, programmers can get lazier and/or programs do more *fiddly bits* that aren't necessary (like spell check as you type for example). Few interfaces get better as time passes, notable exceptions are open source libs: GDAL, FFMPEG etc, without the burden of flashy front ends, I think that shapely/fiona could be added to that list of APIs that got faster over time instead of trying to be everything to everybody like paid software has to be - or people wouldn't buy it.

Comment: Michael, looking at your profile, you're not new to ESRI so I'm surprised you are unaware of how poorly ESRI writes their tools.  I actually posted the times it took for everything above.  Using geometries was faster.  Cursors are generally much, much faster.  For instance, deleting: I just tested a dataset with 169k point features in it.  The DeleteFeatures tool took 29.41 seconds.  I have my own delete features script which opens an UpdateCursor and deletes all of the rows.  That tool took 19.67 seconds.